# Is this the correct approach to my angularJS app?

Tags: angularjs, service, scope

I am learning AngularJS, and I'm not entirely sure this is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do.

I want to create a reusable library that will display the data in the scope using a directive, which will in turn use a template.

What am I hung up on, is how do I communicate the new data to the scope using a service?

I have created a simple plunker that illustrates what I'm trying to do.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y18EzatGYpYPE9MHdVgL?p=info

The service doesn't seem to be following the correct Angular patterns.  I don't think I should be passing the $scope into the service to update it, however, I want to keep the dirty details hidden from the user.  The user shouldn't even have to know that I have a .dataList object on the $scope.

```
dataListApp.service('ngDataListSvc', function() {
  this.init = function($scope) {
    // Pretend this is coming from a database
    $scope.dataList.data = [{Id: 1, Name: 'Fred'}, { Id: 2, Name: 'Barney'}, { Id: 3, Name: 'Bam'}];
    console.log($scope.dataList);
  } 

  this.refresh = function($scope) {
    // Pretend this is coming from a database
    $scope.dataList.data = [{Id: 4, Name: 'Wilma'}, { Id: 5, Name: 'Betty'}, { Id: 6, Name: 'Pebbles'}];
  }
});
```

What is the best approach for modifying the scope in this scenario?  Is there a way to use a scope that would only be encapsulated by the service and the directive, but wouldn't be accessible to anyone else?

Comment: You should leave scope to the controller (directive) or use `controllerAs` which is still internally scoped (i believe). Why would you pass around scope to the service. But i dont understand "wouldn't be accessible to anyone else" ? It runs in the browser, eventhough you put in the service it can still be  accessed, if somebody really wants to.

Comment: @PSL, you're right, technically it's available, I just wanted to avoid making the user worry about loading data and assigning it to the right objects, etc.

Comment: So the question still remains, is there a good way to "hide" the details of modifying the scope in my little library?

Comment: Hide isn't quite the right word.  I'm encapsulating it so that any devs that need to use my library don't have to know much about the inner workings.  Is there a way to call the directive controller functions from outside the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call anything from anywhere... but to do it right you need both a reference to the data you're working with *and* the context in which it should be called. That's a lot trickier than it sounds to do generically.

The problem you're running into is that you have a different philosophy than what AngularJS was founded on. In MVC (or MVW), the Controller's primary purpose is to do what you're trying to avoid having it do: to act as the liaison between back-end services and data models (M) and the front-end UIs (V) that render them and process user interactions. They're basically *the* place where you "wire up" those elements. So by trying to avoid the need to wire them up there, you're basically saying you don't want what the framework's primarily there to give you the ability to do - one good question is whether a different framework would be more suitable for you.

That said it's really not that hard to work around things if you're absolutely committed to doing it. One simple option would be to have a simple attribute directive that does *not* have 'isolate scope' (do not define the scope attribute at all). You would apply this directive on the same DOM element where you place the ng-controller attribute. That directive would then have the same $scope as the controller itself, could ask the injector for the service where you want to get the data, and could handle these definitions.

I modified your Plunkr to illustrate the basic concept:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aT9m4GtFzCsnAEd8k7xR?p=preview

You're basically making a simple directive and wiring up the 'magic' in there:

```
app.directive('addMyService', ['ngDataListSvc', function(ngDataListSvc) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.init = function() {
        ngDataListSvc.init($scope);
      }

      $scope.refresh = function() {
        ngDataListSvc.refresh($scope);
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

If you want a good example of this kind of magic in action, take a look at ngBindOnce, a really cool module Pasquale Vazzanna (a hugely talented AngularJS developer) wrote to allow you to minimize the number of watches you have in a big data model. There are attributes that can be applied to individual elements, and also attributes that are applied to the main container element that provide the wrapper 'magic' it needs to do its work. It's a really good example of what you can do if you want to get super creative with AngularJS directives.

Comment: That's basically what I ended up doing.  I'm not sure I agree with your assessment of what I'm attempting to do.  I'm simply trying to modify the data in $scope so that the view will render accordingly.  I just don't know how to modify the $scope data in an encapsulated way without actually passing the $scope into a service, or creating a function in the scope itself (like you've done here).  If there is a better way to think of this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: But... $scope is just a container for data. What other ways ARE there to modify it except to either pass it to something, or include something locally (directive) that can then see it? I mean, if you set aside crazy hacks like walking the entire $scope chain, recursively, to find something...

Answer (score 0):

What I decided to do was something more along the lines of this...

In my directive, I create a controller and add functions in there that the page controller can call.

```
dataListApp.directive('ngDatalist', ['$compile', '$window', 'ngDataListSvc', function ($compile, $window, ngDataListSvc) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var el = angular.element("<div ng-include='templateUrl'></div>");
            $compile(el)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(el);
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.dataList = {};

            $scope.refreshDataList = function (url) {
                // Not shown in this example...
                ngDataListSvc.refreshGrid(url)
                    .then(function (data) {
                        $scope.dataList.data = data;
                    });
            }
        }]
    };
}]);
```

then in my page controller, I can simply do

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {                   
    $scope.someClick = function () {
        $scope.refreshDataList('@(Url.Action("GetDataList"))');
    }
}]);
```